# Is it possible to pay externally for unconfirmed transaction?

Tags: transactions, mining-pools, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

I have a strange situation. I bought some bitcoins with fiat currency and the seller (trading site) have sent my bitcoins to my private wallet. But the problem is that the transaction has a too low fee (143 sat / byte) to be mined. 
The transaction was sent about 110 hours ago and it is still unconfirmed. It seems that the transaction won't be confirmed or it will be dropped from the mempool.

I can not reach the seller right now (they are ignoring me). So, I would like to pay some miner to mine, my transaction because if it is dropped from the mempool I will lose a great portion of the money.

Is it possible to pay someone (for example to mining pool) to include my transaction in the block chain? For example, I can send some amount of bitcoins with good fee to the miner if I would know that my transaction would be mined.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to know which mining pool will get to add the next block.

Comment: It's a pity.. I just hope that someone will mine it..

Comment: You should create a child-pays-for-parent transaction. Which wallet are you using?

Comment: I am using Bitcoin Core but I don't know which wallet does the sender is using. My purpose is to receive a transaction from the sender.